# Print bar code text file using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, firefox

I have generated a text file which holds the bar code text. At this stage i want to print that file using Javascript with a Generic/Text Only printer. I have 2 questions here:

- How to print this text file using Javascript?
- Can i select a printer (automatically) using Javascript or other browser techniques without user input?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to print this text file using Javascript?

- Load that text file via [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) onto the current page, or a frame, or a new window. You can optionally apply styles using CSS.
- Or You can also load the file directly into the frame or window.

To print, use [`print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing).

> Can i select a printer (automatically) using Javascript or other browser techniques without user input?

No. You can't.

Comment: a bar code file is a text file, this doesn't have any styles or so. text file ideally has to be printed silently.

Comment: @Aqee Styles are optional, only if you loaded the content into an HTML page. If you opened the file in a frame or window directly, no styles can be applied. Just tell the frame/window showing the file to print itself.